# How to prevent duplicate column rows in the MySQL database while keeping the order down

Tags: mysql, sql

How can you please help me I have a table in the database with a column called "recioient_id"
The value of its rows is repeated more than once How do I prevent repeating rows while keeping the order descending and displaying the last row
I have tried so much without a find
I did this query and was good at preventing repetition and did not display the last row
Query which was:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `sender_id` = 1
GROUP BY `recioient_id` DESC
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

Here is a sample table

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fmMB_znYUiy-hvfMgai0a_znOIHjcfU/view?usp=sharing]

I hope to be successful in translation and hope to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per `recioient_id`, use filtering.  I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE m.sender_id = 1 AND
      m.messages_id = (SELECT MAX(m2.messages_id)
                       FROM messages m2
                       WHERE m2.sender_id = m.sender_id AND
                             m2.recioient_id = m.recioient_id
                      )
ORDER BY m.recioient_id;
```

Comment: This is a good thank you but what about the descending order where I can put DESC

Comment: @salem715 . . . Add an `order by` to the outermost `select`, if you want the results in a particular order.

Comment: Thank you. You've solved the descending order by your code. I owe you hope I can find a way to express my gratitude to you